# hard-nested json and pd.json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I started using python and I'm a beginner.
I have been trying to normalize a very nested Json file (see it later).

In simple terms I've 2 main nests that I want to flatten:

- portfolio_item_list (the list contains 2 dictionaries)
- supply token list (a dictionary for each of the previous ones)

I succeeded in flattening them separately by using pd.json_normalize but I can't figure out how to flatten everything to get a table like this (in other words I can't understand how to merge them).

```
     protocol      id   protocol name   chain   tvl asset_usd_value debt_usd_value  net_usd_value   portfolio_item_list.name    optimized_symbol    amount
1   ftm_beefy   Beefy   ftm 239485780,8 512,6956089 0   512,6956089 Yield   WFTM    351,0579442
1   ftm_beefy   Beefy   ftm 239485780,8 512,6956089 0   512,6956089 Yield   TOMB    356,9391582
2   ftm_beefy   Beefy   ftm 239485780,8 106,1679945 0   106,1679945 Yield   SPELL   34050,0303
```

With this code I succeeded in flattening the first level

```
pd.json_normalize(first_data, ["portfolio_item_list"])
```

```
      update_at   name                                     pool_id detail_types  stats.asset_usd_value  stats.debt_usd_value  stats.net_usd_value                           detail.supply_token_list
0  1.651872e+09  Yield  0x429590a528a86a0da0aca9aa7cd087badc790af8     [common]             501.529883                     0           501.529883  [{'id': '0x21be370d5312f44cb42ce377bc9b8a0cef1...
1  1.651872e+09  Yield  0x5eb148a571b0b3d8b8eb46053545e7df833898dc     [common]             106.541151                     0           106.541151  [{'id': '0x468003b688943977e6130f4f68f23aad939...
```

With this other code i succeded in flattening the second (nested) level:

```
pd.json_normalize(first_data, ["portfolio_item_list", 'detail',"supply_token_list"], meta=[['portfolio_item_list','stats'],['portfolio_item_list','pool_id']])
```

```
                                           id chain            name symbol display_symbol optimized_symbol  decimals                                           logo_url protocol_id     price  is_verified  is_core  is_wallet       time_at        amount                          portfolio_item_list.stats                 portfolio_item_list.pool_id
0  0x21be370d5312f44cb42ce377bc9b8a0cef1a4c83   ftm  Wrapped Fantom   WFTM           None             WFTM        18  https://static.debank.com/image/ftm_token/logo...              0.721600         True     True       True  1.600243e+09    346.436940  {'asset_usd_value': 501.5298834625261, 'debt_u...  0x429590a528a86a0da0aca9aa7cd087badc790af8
1  0x6c021ae822bea943b2e66552bde1d2696a53fbb7   ftm            TOMB   TOMB           None             TOMB        18  https://static.debank.com/image/ftm_token/logo...              0.694484         True     True       True  1.622414e+09    362.198146  {'asset_usd_value': 501.5298834625261, 'debt_u...  0x429590a528a86a0da0aca9aa7cd087badc790af8
2  0x468003b688943977e6130f4f68f23aad939a1040   ftm     Spell Token  SPELL           None            SPELL        18  https://static.debank.com/image/ftm_token/logo...              0.003128         True     True       True  1.631158e+09  34060.470295  {'asset_usd_value': 106.54115108398622, 'debt_...  0x5eb148a571b0b3d8b8eb46053545e7df833898dc
```

Here it is my Json:

```
{
  "id": "ftm_beefy",
  "chain": "ftm",
  "name": "Beefy",
  "site_url": "https://app.beefy.finance",
  "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/project/logo_url/ftm_beefy/98a5cc0f4596cbdeb9abe5125ae7e9e7.png",
  "has_supported_portfolio": true,
  "tvl": 242576268.49032995,
  "portfolio_item_list": [
    {
      "stats": {
        "asset_usd_value": 501.5298834625261,
        "debt_usd_value": 0,
        "net_usd_value": 501.5298834625261
      },
      "update_at": 1651872000.6128848,
      "name": "Yield",
      "pool_id": "0x429590a528a86a0da0aca9aa7cd087badc790af8",
      "detail_types": [
        "common"
      ],
      "detail": {
        "supply_token_list": [
          {
            "id": "0x21be370d5312f44cb42ce377bc9b8a0cef1a4c83",
            "chain": "ftm",
            "name": "Wrapped Fantom",
            "symbol": "WFTM",
            "display_symbol": null,
            "optimized_symbol": "WFTM",
            "decimals": 18,
            "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/ftm_token/logo_url/0x21be370d5312f44cb42ce377bc9b8a0cef1a4c83/2b7d91858f9c62aafc8d7778b9c22f57.png",
            "protocol_id": "",
            "price": 0.7216,
            "is_verified": true,
            "is_core": true,
            "is_wallet": true,
            "time_at": 1600242566.0,
            "amount": 346.436940253138
          },
          {
            "id": "0x6c021ae822bea943b2e66552bde1d2696a53fbb7",
            "chain": "ftm",
            "name": "TOMB",
            "symbol": "TOMB",
            "display_symbol": null,
            "optimized_symbol": "TOMB",
            "decimals": 18,
            "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/ftm_token/logo_url/0x6c021ae822bea943b2e66552bde1d2696a53fbb7/7f7b2e861030a443c5941a3db60d164e.png",
            "protocol_id": "",
            "price": 0.6944844703203712,
            "is_verified": true,
            "is_core": true,
            "is_wallet": true,
            "time_at": 1622413912.0,
            "amount": 362.19814571206155
          }
        ]
      },
      "proxy_detail": {}
    },
    {
      "stats": {
        "asset_usd_value": 106.54115108398622,
        "debt_usd_value": 0,
        "net_usd_value": 106.54115108398622
      },
      "update_at": 1651872000.7800875,
      "name": "Yield",
      "pool_id": "0x5eb148a571b0b3d8b8eb46053545e7df833898dc",
      "detail_types": [
        "common"
      ],
      "detail": {
        "supply_token_list": [
          {
            "id": "0x468003b688943977e6130f4f68f23aad939a1040",
            "chain": "ftm",
            "name": "Spell Token",
            "symbol": "SPELL",
            "display_symbol": null,
            "optimized_symbol": "SPELL",
            "decimals": 18,
            "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/ftm_token/logo_url/0x468003b688943977e6130f4f68f23aad939a1040/a1b1003790d9ee1463cacba03eecc1a6.png",
            "protocol_id": "",
            "price": 0.003128,
            "is_verified": true,
            "is_core": true,
            "is_wallet": true,
            "time_at": 1631157987.0,
            "amount": 34060.47029539201
          }
        ]
      },
      "proxy_detail": {}
    }
  ],
  "protocolname": "Beefy"
}
```

EDIT 09/05/2022:
What I need should be similar to the following code, but I need to normalize ['portfolio_item_list', 'stats'] too and i don't know hot do perform it

```
pd.json_normalize(first_data, ['portfolio_item_list', 'detail', 'supply_token_list'], ['id',
 'chain',
 'name',
 'site_url',
 'logo_url',
 'has_supported_portfolio',
 'tvl', ['portfolio_item_list', 'pool_id'],['portfolio_item_list', 'stats']], meta_prefix='m_')
```

Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to get?

```
meta = list(data.keys())
meta.remove('portfolio_item_list')
pd.json_normalize(data, ['portfolio_item_list', 'detail', 'supply_token_list'], meta, meta_prefix='m_')
```

```
                                           id chain            name symbol display_symbol optimized_symbol  decimals                                           logo_url protocol_id     price  is_verified  is_core  is_wallet       time_at        amount       m_id m_chain m_name                 m_site_url                                         m_logo_url m_has_supported_portfolio            m_tvl m_protocolname
0  0x21be370d5312f44cb42ce377bc9b8a0cef1a4c83   ftm  Wrapped Fantom   WFTM           None             WFTM        18  https://static.debank.com/image/ftm_token/logo...              0.721600         True     True       True  1.600243e+09    346.436940  ftm_beefy     ftm  Beefy  https://app.beefy.finance  https://static.debank.com/image/project/logo_u...                      True  242576268.49033          Beefy
1  0x6c021ae822bea943b2e66552bde1d2696a53fbb7   ftm            TOMB   TOMB           None             TOMB        18  https://static.debank.com/image/ftm_token/logo...              0.694484         True     True       True  1.622414e+09    362.198146  ftm_beefy     ftm  Beefy  https://app.beefy.finance  https://static.debank.com/image/project/logo_u...                      True  242576268.49033          Beefy
2  0x468003b688943977e6130f4f68f23aad939a1040   ftm     Spell Token  SPELL           None            SPELL        18  https://static.debank.com/image/ftm_token/logo...              0.003128         True     True       True  1.631158e+09  34060.470295  ftm_beefy     ftm  Beefy  https://app.beefy.finance  https://static.debank.com/image/project/logo_u...                      True  242576268.49033          Beefy
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer. This is not exactly what i'm looking for. I'd like to also add to the output the flattening of the other level present in my Json (e.g. net_usd_value) as in my first sample output.  What I need should be similar to this code, but I need to normalize ['portfolio_item_list', 'stats'] too and i don't know hot do perform it.

Comment: pd.json_normalize(first_data, ['portfolio_item_list', 'detail', 'supply_token_list'], ['id',
 'chain',
 'name',
 'site_url',
 'logo_url',
 'has_supported_portfolio',
 'tvl', ['portfolio_item_list', 'pool_id'],['portfolio_item_list', 'stats']], meta_prefix='m_')